# How do I undo the patch to openvpn recommended by Private Tunnel?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

i was making new connection with openvpn by documents on privatetunnel.com and at the end of docs i enter this command in terminal and after that openvpn in broken. i remove open vpn with apt-get remove openvpn and one  time with purge command after that i install again openvpn but it's not available in creation of new connection.

the code i entered and everything gone wrong is this:

```
mv /usr/sbin/openvpn /usr/local/sbin; echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/sbin/openvpn $* --ns-cert-type server &\ntrap "kill $!" EXIT\nwait $!\n' > /usr/sbin/openvpn; chmod +x /usr/sbin/openvpn
```

i just want undo this command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you overwrote /usr/sbin/openvpn (the openvpn binary). Can you show me the output of:

```
# file /usr/sbin/openvpn
```

Comment: /usr/sbin/openvpn: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=de99a62643c8cbb6f938b8003661d1ad02ec01c3, stripped

Comment: and # which openvpn

Comment: i use this command and openvpn is backed:)
sudo apt-get -y install network-manager-openvpn

Answer (score 0):

To undo the specific command you included in the question post, run:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/sbin/openvpn /usr/sbin/
```

### Explanation:

The original command moved the file `openvpn` from `/usr/sbin/` to `/usr/local/sbin/`, and then it created a script called `openvpn` in `/usr/sbin/`. To undo this, we need to move the original file `/usr/local/sbin/openvpn` to `/usr/sbin/`, overwriting the script.